# Why is “des Reisens” used instead of “der Reisen” in this passage?

Tags: grammar, genitive, grammatical-number, nominalization

My question is about the following passage from *Die Verwandlung:*

> Die geschäftlichen Aufregungen sind viel größer, als im eigentlichen Geschäft zu Hause, und außerdem ist mir noch diese Plage (**des Reisens**) auferlegt, die Sorgen um die Zuganschlüsse, das unregelmäßige, schlechte Essen, ein immer wechselnder, nie andauernder, nie herzlich werdender menschlicher Verkehr.

*Die Reise* is a feminine noun. The plural form is *die Reisen,* the geneative plural is *der Reisen.* Why is *des Reisens* used instead? That is what I can find in a dictionary.

Also, *reisen* is a verb. Could it be that *reisen* here has just been nominalized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a nominalized verb (das Reisen). The author is not speaking of a trip in particular (that'd be "die Reise", feminine), but rather of travelling in general ("das Reisen"). So the translation is roughly "this plague of (the) travelling", or "this plague of having to travel that is forced on me"